# CAKEPHPでMS SQLServerへ接続するための定義（app.php）を教えてください

Tags: cakephp, sql-server

当方の開発端末はフレームワークを使わずPHP7.0のWebアプリケーションを仕上げた実績があります。MSSQL2008R2及びOracle11gをデータベースとしたサイトで、必要なdllを入手してphp.iniへ以下追記を図ったことで接続を達成できている認識です。

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
```

===質問===
フレームワークを採用した開発にチャレンジしようとCakePHP3の参考書を入手しました。SQLiteとMySQLのみ接続のための定義が紹介されておりました。自身の応用能力もないことから、MSSQL（Oracle11g）と接続を達成する上での定義方法が分かりません。
どのようにapp.phpを編集すればMSSQL（Oracle11g）との接続が達成できるのか教えてくださいませんか？
フレームワークなしで接続が達成できている端末ならば、そんな大きな障壁ではないことを願っています。

ただ今、app.phpの以下について変更したうえ、http://localhost：8765/の表示を確認したところ
DataBase接続状況に進展が得られた模様です。取り急ぎご報告です。
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
'encoding' => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: データベースの接続についての公式ドキュメントは次のものです。合わせて確認してください。https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm/database-basics.html#database-configuration

Answer (score 1):

自己解決致しました、つまりMSSQLServerへの接続が達成されました。
Oracleはまだですが．．．

参考にしたサイトはこちらです。
https://teratail.com/questions/39752

具体的な手立ては本文に追記してあるとおりですがapp.php内について以下のように変更を加えました。
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
'encoding' => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,

Answer (score 0):

Oracleへの接続については、公式ではサポートされていません。

以下のプラグインを導入して接続します。

CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver: CakePHP 3 Driver for Oracle Database https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver

PHPへOCI8の拡張は追加済みのようですので、 `driver` は `CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\Driver\OracleOCI`を指定すればよいでしょう。

その他、`Datasource`の設定については、プラグインのREADMEを参照してください。